# Auto Script Generator

Tags: command-line, scripts

I want to generate a script for hard disk partitions

```
#!/bin/bash
# Check if blkid is installed
command -v blkid > /dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "blkid is required but not installed. Aborting."; exit 1; }

# Specify the output script file
output_script="create_partitions2.sh"
# Generate mkdir commands for hard disk partitions based on names and labels
echo "#!/bin/bash" > "$output_script"
echo "" >> "$output_script"
echo "# Auto-generated script to create directories for hard disk partitions" >> "$output_script"
echo "echo 'Creating directories for hard disk partitions...'" >> "$output_script"

# Use blkid to get information about partitions
blkid -o list | awk '{print $1 "/ "  $3 }' | cut -d '/' -f 3-4 | cut -d '/' -f 1,2 | awk '{print "    mkdir /media/"   ($2=="(not" ? $1 : $2)    }' >> "$output_script"
echo "echo 'Giving Permission to the Created Directories...'" >> "$output_script"
blkid -o list | awk '{print $1 "/ "  $3 }' | cut -d '/' -f 3-4 | cut -d '/' -f 1,2 | awk '{print "    chmod 777 /media/"   ($2=="(not" ? $1 : $2) " -R"   }' >> "$output_script"
echo "echo 'Mounting Partitions to the Created Directories...'" >> "$output_script"
blkid -o list | awk '{print $1 "/ "  $3 }' | cut -d '/' -f 3-4 | cut -d '/' -f 1,2 | awk '{print "    mount /dev/" $1 " /media/"   ($2=="(not" ? $1 : $2)    }' >> "$output_script"
echo "echo 'Directories created successfully.'" >> "$output_script"

# Make the script executable
chmod +x "$output_script"
```

It gives me two first empty lines. I want to remove those lines and also one for mounted partition line.

Comment: That is a broad question ... And that is a very bad script (sorry) ... Probably explain more what starting point/situation you have and what result you want to achieve and that might help somebody help you.

Comment: i want "mkdir /media/sda1, mkdir /media/sda2.....

Comment: I see, although I don’t agree on the concept as device names do change and they might suddenly constantly modify, but `blkid` might not be the tool you want for a few reasons … See if you like the output of for example `/bin/lsblk -e 7,11 -nlo TYPE,NAME | /bin/awk '/part/ {print $2}'` better?

Comment: ... or perhaps even use the `--json` output of `lsblk` so you can write a `jq` filter rather than relying on potentially fragile textual parsing

Comment: @Raffa in given command "-e 7,11" is useless? why you add this?

Comment: No, it's not useless ... the `-e` option means exclude ... `7` are `loop` block devices used for SNAP mounts and `11` are `sr` block devices (optical drives) ... see the output of `cat /proc/devices` for info ... You don't want those in the output regardless of what parsing method you use (after the pipe `|`) ... A well controlled output makes text parsing more reliable and accurate.

Comment: @Raffa one more issue i am facing, that changing the order of switch the command will give me error, i am unable to understand it some commands do not take care of order of switches, like cp cammand does not care you can use any switch any where in the command lsblk -nlo is correct, but lsblk -lno or lsblk -oln not work? why???

Comment: The option `-o` expects the output format as an argument directly after it e.g. `-o TYPE,NAME` and that’s why it has to be the last of the combined options … Otherwise, both  `-nlo …` or `-lno …` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your method of extracting partitions names can be inconsistent and will include `loop`, `zram`, `zswap` ... etc. devices as well as it will print a two line header (that's most likely why you're getting the two empty lines).

You'll probably want to use a more resourceful tool (like [`lsblk`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/lsblk.8.html)) in order to control the output more and then text-process it ... I'm not intending to write your script for you, but you can use this as a template:

```
lsblk -e 7,11 -nlo TYPE,NAME |
awk '/part/ {print $2}' |
xargs -I {} bash -c 'echo mkdir /media/"$1"; echo mount /dev/"$1" /media/"$1"' bash {}
```

... which will output something like this:

```
mkdir /media/sda1
mount /dev/sda1 /media/sda1
mkdir /media/sda2
mount /dev/sda2 /media/sda2
```

... or make `lsblk` output in the form of a fixed data structure like `--json` and then parse it like for example:

```
lsblk -e 7,11 --json -nlo TYPE,NAME |
jq -r '.blockdevices[] | select(."type" == "part") | ."name"' |
xargs -I {} bash -c 'echo mkdir /media/"$1"; echo mount /dev/"$1" /media/"$1"' bash {}
```

... which will yield the same result.

**Notice** that `/media` is usually utilized for udisks automatic/manual mounts for users under subdirectories named after each username … I understand that you might not expect a username as `sda1` or `nvme*` but it might be a better idea if you chose a different target parent directory like `/mnt` for example.